# Which tool can tidy/indent HTML5?

Tags: html5, code

I've already spent about 2 hours searching google and trying various tools but either they don't do indent tags per say or they aren't HTML5 compatible such as the famous [HTML tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) which was last updated 3 years ago…

N.B. I don't want to apply this to the source of a page (like PHP or JS would do) but to the code in the editor so that a clear hierarchy appears between tags.

Ideally I'd like a Mac OS X tool but I'll take any online tool and in last resot a Wine compatible one.

P.S. at the moment I use Coda from Panic

Comment: [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) supports code-formatting via SHIFT+ALT+F, most editors have a similar function – check the manual of one you use. See also: http://groups.google.com/group/coda-users/browse_thread/thread/018cffe184dac80a?pli=1

Comment: Netbeans does it (thx) but not Coda as your link shows.

Comment: But there are two other programs mentioned in the linked discussion that do…

Comment: I imagine if you look you will find a Coda extension that adds support for HTML5 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was looking for an online tool and that's probably why I failed to find anything.
I was pointed to the [Coda plugin PHP & Toolkit](http://www.chipwreck.de/blog/software/coda-php/) that does it.
Also most HTML editors like Taco do it natively (but not Coda).

Answer (score 7):

There's now an HTML5 version of tidy, found here:
https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5.

Answer (score 6):

**Aptana Studio 2** does what you want in the menu Edit > Format. I've used it and it formats html, css and javascript.

The WYSIWYG editor BlueGriffon also can also format html when you open a file.

Both solutions are free and open-source, but Aptana might be better. I'm not sure if BG keeps all the code unchanged, probably not.

**Notes:**

1. Aptana 2 needs to be properly configured after you install it, but
   it's a great html5/css/javascript editor/IDE. The default config sucks a little.
2. Aptana 3 might not do what you want. The version I've tried didn't
   do it.

Comment: Personally, I dislike it for the Eclipsish IDE (I don't like Eclipse :P).

Comment: Aptana is a great program for html/css/js, keeping track of opening and closing bracket or braces in javascript in really large functions is a pain in dreamweaver.

Comment: Thank you this has just saved my life after moving my project files from another IDE to Aptana and the indentation getting messed up. I was manually re-indenting all my thousands upon thousands of lines. In Aptana 3 this is under the Source menu > Format.

Answer (score 1):

I humbly suggest [Espresso 2](https://espressoapp.com/).

From their website:

> The one and only CSSEdit 3 — CSSEdit's award-winning visual tools, now
> inside Espresso. With awesome CSS3 support for multi-browser
> gradients, shadows and more.
>
> Web Preview with X-ray — See how your CSS affects web layouts,
> visualize margins and padding, and quickly find the relevant style
> rules for any page element.
>
> Powerful and Efficient Coding — CodeSense, code folding, smart
> snippets, Zen coding and the drag-and-drop Navigator help you write
> better code in less time.
>
> Live Styling and Overrides — Edit any website's CSS and see it update
> in real-time. No need to save, publish or reload. Experimenting and
> tweaking has never been this fun.
>
> Effortless Sync and Publishing — With Quick Publish, Server Sync and
> Browse, you have the right tool for any server-based workflow. The new
> Vroom engine is super-fast.
>
> A Workspace That Fits Into Your Workflow — The innovative Workspace
> gives you the flexibility of Tabs while integrating smoothly with your
> Project files.
>
> Fantastic Find — Needle and haystack, meet Espresso. Project-wide Find
> and Replace, Quick Filter and colorized regex make searching through
> files or text a breeze.
>
> Language Support — Improved HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript and PHP; all-new
> Ruby, Python, Apache and Markdown. Or extend Espresso with XML/JS
> Sugars.

You could read a [review](https://web.archive.org/web/20170504143229/http://mac.appstorm.net:80/reviews/web-dev-review/espresso-2-create-and-edit-css3-like-never-before/) from Mac Appstorm to have an idea of the quality. They give it **10/10**.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse seems to do a decent job of indenting/formatting HTML5.  You just use the usual format command (Ctrl-Shift-F) on an HTML file loaded in the HMTL editor and it will reformat it.

To adjust it, go to preferences --> web --> html files --> editor.  You can also control validation here.  (I'm using Eclipse v4.2.2.)

Note that the HTML editor requires that your  Eclipse installation include the Web Tools Platform (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56115/150016) for details).

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Mac OS X tool that does the job, I'd say [TextMate](http://macromates.com/).

I usually do a lot of re-indenting and the best one that I've been able to find has been that one.

What I like is that it doesn't actually **rearranges** your code, but it **re-indents** it, in a form that checks the nesting and indents by level, **not by tags**.

The "Indent Selection" feature is specially useful.

Comment: I use textmate, when did they introduce a good formatting action for HTML? Please share as all the ones I've found have been pretty bad.  Though I am still using 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

[JetBrains PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) works great and intuitive with indents in HTML, CSS or PHP.
Type of indent (tabs or spaces) you can change in PHPStorm settings.

Answer (score 0):

Dirtymarkup.com  is my go to for quickly formatting HTML and JS.